# Too many attributes on enum?

Tags: oop, enums

My system currently runs in differents environments.

I got a Environment enum on my system, something like this

```
public enum Environment {

    [UsePayPal(false)]
    [ServerInstallDir("InstallPathOnServer")]
    [IntegrationSystemURI("localhost/someFakeURI")]
    [UpdateSomeInfo(true)]
    [QueuePrefix("DEV")]
    [UseCache(false)]
    [AnotherSystemURI("localhost/anotherFakeURI")]
    Development = 0,

    [UsePayPal(false)]
    [ServerInstallDir("InstallPathOnBUILDServer")]
    [IntegrationSystemURI("build-server/someFakeURI")]
    [UpdateSomeInfo(true)]
    [QueuePrefix("QA")]
    [UseCache(false)]
    [AnotherSystemURI("build-server/anotherFakeURI")]
    QA = 1,

    [UsePayPal(true)]
    [ServerInstallDir("InstallPathOnServer")]
    [IntegrationSystemURI("someservice.com/URI")]
    [UpdateSomeInfo(true)]
    [QueuePrefix("PRD")]
    [UseCache(true)]
    [AnotherSystemURI("anotherservice/URI")]
    Production = 2,
}
```

I'm working like this, because I dont like code like

```
if(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT == Environment.QA || CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT == Environment.DEV)
    EnableCache()
```

or

```
if(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT == Environment.QA || CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT == Environment.DEV){
    DoSomeStuff();
}
```

because I think that's scatter my logic all over the system, and not on a single point.

If some day I add another Test Enviroment, I dont need to go all over my code to see if I work like on Development, QA or Production enviroment.

Ok, but, with all that config I may end up with too maby attributes on my Enum, lets say, in 3 years each enum value will have 15~20 attributes, and that looks weird.

What do you guys think? How do you usually handle this situation? Its really too many attributes, or thats ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `Environment` class with a `private` constructor and as many properties as you need to describe the environment, and expose `static readonly` instances as public properties. You can also have an `Environment.Current` property that points to one of these instances.

Example code:

```
sealed class Environment
{
    // The current environment is going to be one of these -- 1:1 mapping to enum values
    // You might also make these properties if there's fine print pointing towards that
    public static readonly Environment TestEnvironment;
    public static readonly Environment ProductionEnvironment;

    // Access the environment through this
    public static Environment Current { get; set; }

    static Environment()
    {
        TestEnvironment = new Environment {
            UsePayPal = false,
            ServerInstallDir = "/test"
        };
        ProductionEnvironment = new Environment { 
            UsePayPal = true, 
            ServerInstallDir = "/prod"
        };
    }

    // Environment propeties here:
    public bool UsePayPal { get; private set; }
    public string ServerInstallDir { get; private set; }

    // We don't want anyone to create "unauthorized" instances of Environment
    private Environment() {}
}
```

Use it like:

```
Environment.Current = Environment.TestEnvironment;

// later on...
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Current.ServerInstallDir);
```